# Couchdb replication to Algolia (elastic search as a service)

Tags: couchdb, replication, algolia

There is an app that has elastic search via Algolia (elastic search) and algolia features RESTFul API to do operations on the data (add / remove doc etc).

There is also core persistence via PouchDB=CouchDB constant replication.

I want to make sure everytime a new document appears in CouchDB - it gets "replicated"/added to the algolia search.

Provided Algolia has restful API - am I correct that it would be relatively easy to setup filtered replication (more like copying) over to Algolia?

If not - what are the challenges?

Comment: Algolia doesn't rely on Elastic Search. It's our own engine, built in-house. Unfortunately, I cannot help you with couchDB but I wanted to let you know about Algolia. You can read more about our engine here: https://blog.algolia.com/inside-the-algolia-engine-part-1-indexing-vs-search/

Comment: Hey - sorry didn't know that! We are also super happy with the service btw;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple to replicate a couchdb database, by watching to changes in the `_changes` endpoint in some long-running script. Then you call `saveObjects` with the Algolia API client.

see also what we did to replicate the npm couchdb database into Algolia here: https://github.com/algolia/npm-search